Вывод новостных статей за определённый период времени
Мне нужно создать парсер и собрать данные с новостного сайта Газета РУ (https://www.gazeta.ru/) за год (с 01.01.2023 до 01.01.2024). Вопрос: как мне надо изменить ссылку чтобы вывести все новости за приведённую дату? Знаю, что что-то надо написать в самом URL.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
